# my request body does not make it (?) to my application

Tags: node.js, post

my request body from my curl is not making it to my note.js express application:

curl request (done with postman):

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:5000/api/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Name",
    "fullName": "Name Name"
}'
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api/', router);

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.status(200).json({
        "Received" : "OK"
    })
})

const server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server running on port 5000')
})
```

the console.log does not log out the req.body but only undefined

what am I missing?

Comment: Where is `successResponse` code?

Comment: i changed the code to:
   res.status(200).json({
        "Received" : "OK"
    }). But as i said below i found the problem. Do you agree?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to reorder the sequence and declarations from your code to:

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

const router = express.Router();
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.status(200).json({
        "Received" : "OK"
    })
})
app.use('/api', router); //<--remove last slash in this route
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue...

the app.use('/api/', router); needs to be right before creating and starting the server or after the post route.